# Does an OpenSSH agent keep the unencrypted key or the passphrase in memory?

Tags: memory, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-agent

Just to be explicit and clear.  Does the OpenSSH agent keep the unencrypted private key in memory or does it keep the passphrase in memory, and decrypt the key as it needs it?  I think [this question, 9650410](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650410/what-mechanisms-does-ssh-agent-use-to-keep-unlocked-private-keys-secure-in-memor), answers me indirectly.  (The *unencrypted private key* is in memory.)

I'm not a coder and couldn't make sense of of the source if I tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TortoiseGit with openssh key not authenticating using ssh-agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516119/tortoisegit-with-openssh-key-not-authenticating-using-ssh-agent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ssh-agent uses the passphrase *once* to decrypt the private key, and the decrypted private key is held in memory. The passphrase is used only initially.

See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39837/does-ssh-agent-store-the-ssh-key-passwords-in-cleartext-in-the-memory

Comment: Please don't just link to another answer. If it is the same, then flag the question as duplicate

Comment: Good idea, but flagging requires more reputation than I currently have!